# Error while running joint_state_publisher

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been trying to bring up the joint state publisher through the launch file using the below command:

```
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" output="screen">
   <rosparam param="source_list">[joint_states]</rosparam>
   <rosparam param="use_gui">FALSE</rosparam>
</node>`
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 327, in <module>
    jsp = JointStatePublisher()
  
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 25, in __init__
    
robot = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(description).getElementsByTagName('robot')[0]
  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1930, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)

TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not None



[joint_state_publisher-7] process has died [pid 6443, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/asimov3/.ros/log/474b6a1a-3077-11e5-9d8c-e8de270f798c/joint_state_publisher-7.log].
log file: /home/asimov3/.ros/log/474b6a1a-3077-11e5-9d8c-e8de270f798c/joint_state_publisher-7*.log
```

Could anyone please clarify why this error is thrown?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214315/error-while-running-joint_state_publisher/) by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ehm, I guess we should take a closer look at this line:

```
robot = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(description).getElementsByTagName('robot')[0]
```

Maybe you should try another launchfile with a Joint state publisher, could be something wrong with your model (missing, or malformed robot tag).

You could also try my package: I have a robot in there ... robot state should work
(it does for me with ros indigo on Ubuntu Trusty 64 Bits) (btw. my rviz file is a bit messed up)

https://github.com/Hacks4ROS/h4r_rapid_robot_xacros/blob/develop/launch/diff_drive_bot.launch

Btw, are you sure your model is there?

I just tried what happpens when the robot model is not there -> joint state publisher crashes.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on 2015-07-23**:
Hi Cyborb, Thanks for the reply. I missed to add the model:
`

`
Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-23**:
You're welcome ;-)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-04-05**:
I just got this error when I was running joint_state_publisher in a different namespace than the one where the `robot_description` resides.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-04-05**:
There is something a little irregular (or not?) where joint_state_publisher looks for every parameter in the private namespace first, and then the public  https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/kinetic-devel/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher#L14

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2017-11-07**:
How did you fix the namespace issue?